# junit @RunWith(Parameterized.class) annotation is throwing null

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have a test which is extending to baseTest which is where I have included the parameters.

ATest.class

```
public class ATest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(fSomething);
    }
}
```

BaseTest.class

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class BaseTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public Boolean fSomething;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "fSomething  {0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{true}, {false}});
    }
}
```

i am getting null value. If i set the constructor i am getting this error

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [boolean arg0] in constructor.
```

Can someone help me understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you use Jupiter from jUnit 5, but jUnit 4 API.

If you use jUnit 5, reimplement the test using `@ParametrizedTest` annotation instead. Start here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

If you want to stick with the jUnit 4 API for this particular test, replace the import for the `@Test` annotation: Instead of `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` (jUnit 5) use `org.junit.Test` (jUnit 4).

---

For completeness, I recommend adding a constructor for the parameters in the base test class:

```java
public BaseTest(Boolean fSomething) {
    this.fSomething = fSomething;
}
```

... or use Lombok annotation `@AllArgsConstructor` or `@RequiredArgsConstructor` in case you make the field `final` (preferred).

Comment: Thank you. Changing it to org.junit.Test worked :)

Answer (score -1):

In the code posted , i see @Test is being used in the derived class and using @parameterized in base class, as you are using both the annotation you see these issues. check the usage of it.